# Angular 2 how to provide different dependencies to children of the same component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

From angular's [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#useclass), I see that a child component can ask for a dependency using abstract class, and the parent can provide concrete class for child's dependency.
For example:

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers:[{provide: AbstractService, useClass: ConcreteService}]
})
export class ParentComponent{}

@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent{
    constructor(private service:AbstractService){}
}
```

By doing this, child component can be very flexible. It can behave differently depending on the dependency it's parent inject into it.
However, what if a parent has multiple child of the same kind, how does it provide different dependencies for each child.
Say I have a child component called Searchbar. A parent needs to have two Searchbars, one searching some hardcoded dummy data, one does GET request to the server. I can add another layer by wrapping each of the child with different parent in order to provide different services. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I made myself clear in the question. However after rethinking the architecture I'm gonna answer my own question. Please comment if you have better solution.
The question was how to provide same components different services. Like how to inject a button a service to submit form, the other button a service to save file, giving that these two buttons are under the same parent and from the same component class.
I could inject both services to the button and set a flag on the button to use one of the service. This is not extensible and will make the button very complex.
the better way is making the button dumb. Button shouldn't care about how to handle data. It should only emit event when user click and let the parent to handle other things.
Same with the Searchbar above. Searchbar shouldn't care about where data is from, parent should do all the query and pass a cleanly formatted array of data to searchbar.
**Update 9/6/16**
With the release of Angular RC5 and RC6, Angular introduced [NgModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html). Components in the same module shares the dependencies listed in the module. If we want to control the dependency of an individual component, we could probably create a module for each component. At least this is what I see from [Angular Material](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjI5aCY9frOAhUH1R4KHdeZAr4QFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fangular%2Fmaterial2&usg=AFQjCNF7UPAjDe1hDNI5DfpbhH6KAYdG-Q&sig2=IUQcYzAHoGUkjVXBkSzZQA&cad=rjt). But still, I would try to make most of the components dumb so that they require no dependency.

Comment: You can still add providers to components. That's the same as before. Only `directives` and `pipes` were removed from `@Component()`. You can't control providers scope within a single component. You can pass services using binding from parent to child component though. `<button [service]="service1"></button><button [service]="service2"></button>` where the parent component injects `service1` and `service2`

Answer (score 0):

Answering your original question: (If I understood it currently)

For some reason if you use the `provide: ... useClass: ...` syntax and the "class used" (`ConcreteService` in your case) has different dependencies than the class you asked for (`AbstractService` in your case), Angular fail to inject those dependency unless you implicitly declare them:

```
{
    provide: AbstractClass,
    useClass: ConcreteClass,
    deps: [SomeServiceUsedInConcreteClass, ...]
}
```

If anybody knows a better / alternative way of accomplishing the same thing, please comment.